# What to use after "when" present simple or continuous?

Tags: differences

For instance:

a) When you sing, I feel like I hear angels sing.

b) When you're singing, I feel like I hear angels sing.

They are most likely both possible, if so, what are the differences?

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are both possible.

The difference here as you highlighted in your question is between the tenses, in (a) you are using the present simple tense, and in (b) you are using the present continuous tense.

See [here](https://learnenglishkids.britishcouncil.org/en/grammar-practice/present-simple-and-present-continuous):

As the linked guide explains: -

> We use the present simple to talk about routines – what you do every
>   day or every week. We use the present continuous to talk about things
>   you are doing now.

and [here](http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-sing.html) which lists the various conjugations of the verb 'sing'

In your examples:

> a) When you sing, I feel like I hear angels sing.

You would use this to refer generally to the feeling you experience when the person sings. You would use this if they were not in the process of singing.

So for instance you could be out for a meal with them, and recollecting the experience you feel when they sing.

> When you're singing, I feel like I hear angels sing.

This is using the present continuous tense 'you are singing', you would say this to someone who was actually singing in this present moment.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is correct to say "I feel like I hear angels singing"  at the end of your sentence.  The difference between using the present simple or present progressive at the beginning of the sentence is really just a theoretical grammatical difference.  I don't think there is any real difference in the meaning of the two sentences.